# A method to add a point into a line string in C#

Tags: line, vertices

I am working on a way to add a point(x,y) into a line. In fact a line consist of set of point with an order in them. so when I want to add point into line I must consider their order. In fact I must find two points which are before and after my point and then add it between them. I can work with most of liberaries as sharpmap,NetTopologySuit and etc. but none of them give me this ability.

I think I must calculate distance between point and sublinestring in a line and each one with lower distance will be the line that I must add my point to it.
[image]

the above image is what I want. A line is an array of points. so how can I add my point in this array with considering its order in array,I dont know where I place my point in that array Is there any better way to do this?any algorithm or things like that?

Comment: The linestring conceptually represents an ordered sequence of points, or a boundary, or a road, or something else entirely. What does your linestring represent? In your example, why do you want the point to go in that position? Equivalently, why doesn't the black line go to the new (green) point before or after the other two points? The logic for that is critical to determining what the approach should be.  When you can say that, we can possibly help more.

Comment: @BradHards thanks for your help, In fact I want to perform a shape editing by adding vertexes, the shape is boundary of a polygon or a simple poly line.can you suggest me some solutions for this kind of editing?

Comment: Then there is no right answer. Why should the shape be changed in some particular way? If you can't explain the logic, how can the computer possibly implement it? Perhaps the best approach is to have the user drag and drop the line.

Comment: @BradHards yes the green point comes from user's mouse click,I can get the clicked position in lat and long using Sharpmap library. But I have problem in editing line with new point

Comment: I was suggesting don't accept random mouse clicks, because there is no way to know what the user really meant by the click. Instead, only allow drag'n'drop of the existing shape; or ensure that the user selects the line segment to modify, or some other equivalent UI design approach.

Comment: @BradHards thanks for your help. But when I get users point how can I edit the line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43631/discussion-between-bradhards-and-majid-hojati).